# Mysql query optimisation foreign keys

Tags: mysql, optimization, join, foreign-keys

I have a master table and a child table with one foreign key. When I join between these two tables and use explain statement to analyse the performance

1. I am getting the explain output as "Type=ALL" which is considered as worst for performance. How can I improve the performance of this join.
2. explain output only shows "possible_keys: cid_index" instead of key and keylength

Here is a test case

```
 CREATE TABLE `master` (
  `mid` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `mname` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`mid`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=3 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1


select * from master;
+-----+-------+
| mid | mname |
+-----+-------+
|   1 | one   |
|   2 | two   |
+-----+-------+
2 rows in set (0.25 sec)


 CREATE TABLE `child` (
  `cid` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `cname` varchar(10) NOT NULL,
  `Ccid` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`cid`),
  KEY `cid_index` (`Ccid`),
  CONSTRAINT `new_fk_constraint` FOREIGN KEY (`Ccid`) REFERENCES `master` (`mid`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=3 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1



 select * from child;
+-----+-------+------+
| cid | cname | Ccid |
+-----+-------+------+
|   1 | Cone  |    1 |
|   2 | ctwo  |    2 |
+-----+-------+------+
2 rows in set (0.12 sec)



explain select m.*,c.* from master m join child c on  m.mid=c.Ccid \G
*************************** 1. row ***************************
           id: 1
  select_type: SIMPLE
        table: m
         type: ALL
possible_keys: PRIMARY
          key: NULL
      key_len: NULL
          ref: NULL
         rows: 2
        Extra:
*************************** 2. row ***************************
           id: 1
  select_type: SIMPLE
        table: c
         type: ALL
possible_keys: cid_index
          key: NULL
      key_len: NULL
          ref: NULL
         rows: 2
        Extra: Using where; Using join buffer
2 rows in set (0.23 sec)
```

Comment: How many rows of data do you have in the table? From your example it seems like 4 rows? Using a index here is not efficient as a table scan can be done quicker with such small amounts of data. Remember a query execution plan will change over time.

Comment: `JOIN` is a Cartesian product hence using indexes is pointless?

Comment: I increased the count of records to 10 in each. Now MySQL uses indexes for comparisons. Must be one of those `Query Optimisation` tricks, weighing overheads.

Comment: Namphibian, DoSparKot
  Thanks for the response. I tried adding more rows in master and then it tries to pickup the index from master.. But the child table is still not picking up the index.. 

           id: 1
  select_type: SIMPLE
        table: c
         type: ALL
possible_keys: cid_index
          key: NULL
      key_len: NULL
          ref: NULL
         rows: 9
        Extra:

           id: 1
  select_type: SIMPLE
        table: m
         type: eq_ref
possible_keys: PRIMARY
          key: PRIMARY
      key_len: 8
          ref: test.c.Ccid
         rows: 1
        Extra:

Comment: Double check if changing `'Ccid' bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,` into `'Ccid' bigint(20) NOT NULL,` makes any difference.

Answer (score 3):

If the table is too small, with not much to filter , the performance might not be as expected. Usually, if the where clause filters more than x%(around 30%), the whole table scan will be more efficient. Please check the [On mysql performance](http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2006/06/02/indexes-in-mysql/)

Also you can try to force the index and check if the index is being utilized

```
explain select m.*,c.* 
from master m 
join child c force index(Ccid) 
on  m.mid=c.Ccid
```